# Bell Fibe. Offsite TV control via VPN

Tags: vpn, tv

I have a VPN server set up behind my Bell Fibe router via port forwarding on an old Mac with FreeDNS. Connection works perfectly and all other services inside my home are accessible.

Is it possible to get/see Bells Fibe TV service via the same method? My Bell Fibe iOS app can't "see" the receiver for me to control it via VPN and I'd like to if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a multicast/zeroconf/bonjour issue. The VPN is on a different VLAN and IP range, therefore the auto configuration broadcasts between the FibeTV box and the remote app are blocked. If you have a AppleTV at home and can't airplay to it via VPN, it's for the same reason as this. You either need a VPN that operates in bridge mode, or some sort of bonjour bridging.

Use bonjour browser http://www.tildesoft.com/ while at home to see if indeed the FibeTV Box is sending a Bonjour request, and then again at the remote side to see if it's still there.